# (mariadb) SQL error 1064 when creating table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, mariadb-10.5

I'm trying to create a discord bot with python and need a database Table for listing member warnings.
but when I'm trying to make a table in the database I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\.Python\moalmeme-test-bot\db.py", line 21, in <module>
    setup()
  File "D:\.Python\moalmeme-test-bot\db.py", line 18, in setup
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warns` (warn_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, discord_member_id VARCHAR, discord_server_id VARCHAR, reason VARCHAR);")
  File "D:\.Python\moalmeme-test-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 307, in execute
    self._readresponse()
mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'discord_server_id VARCHAR, reason VARCHAR)' at line 1
```

this is my code:

```py
import mariadb
import sys

connection = mariadb.connect(
    user=os.getenv("DB_USER"),
    password=os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    host=os.getenv("DB_HOST"),
    port=os.getenv("DB_PORT"),
    database=os.getenv("DB_NAME")
)

cur = connection.cursor()


def setup():
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warns` (warn_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, discord_member_id VARCHAR, discord_server_id VARCHAR, reason VARCHAR);")


setup()
```

python version: 3.10
mariaDB server version: 10.5
mariaDB python package version: 1.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your column **varchar** datatype don't have the lengths.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warns` (warn_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, discord_member_id VARCHAR(3), discord_server_id VARCHAR(3), reason VARCHAR(100));
```

Comment: discord user ids and discord guild ids are variable between 17 to 20 characters. I can't give it a fixed length in DB

Comment: varchar is not fix character, varchar(17) means you can store up to 17 characters.